# How to trigger Azure Data Factory pipeline using PowerShell (Azure Automation)?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

I was wondering if it were possible to trigger Data Factory dynamically using PowerShell? Are there scripts available or some workarounds using APIs?

For example after scaling the database from S2 -> S9 using PowerShell I'd like to trigger specific Data Factory pipelines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this something you might be looking for?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers

Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactory $df -PipelineName "Adfv2QuickStartPipeline" -ParameterFile .\PipelineParameters.json

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Can you please mark it as an answer in that case? Thanks!

Comment: If you have already created triggers using UI in azure data factory than this solution will work? if yes than how?